# Bash automation SFTP script not moving the last file once in a while

Tags: ftp, sftp, bash-scripting, expect

I have developed a bash script for moving files to FTP only when a particular CSV is available in remote server. A job from another Data quality tool calls this script. Script is working fine, but it is not moving the last file (`Control_File.csv`) once in a while and exiting the script. It is hard to predict when it misses. Below is the script. Any ideas on why it is not moving the last file once in a while?

**NOTE:** I can't use SSH keys, that's why using expect package and masked server details and credentials in below script.

```
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
LOG_LOCATION="/pken4o/shared/config/domains/edq_domain/config/fmwconfig/edq/oedq.local.home/landingarea/53/Script_Log"

exec &>> $LOG_LOCATION/File_Transfer_Log.log

printf "\nDate:$(date -u)"

lockfile="/pken4o/shared/config/domains/edq_domain/config/fmwconfig/edq/oedq.local.home/landingarea/53/DQ_Dashboard_$today.csv"

retval=0
testlock(){
if [ -e "$lockfile" ]; then
       retval=1
    else
        retval=2
    fi
}

testlock
if [ "$retval" == 1 ]
then
     printf "\nDQ_Dashboard_$today.csv File exists"
     expect -c "
     set timeout 180
     eval spawn sftp USER@SERVER
     expect \"USER's password:\"
     send \"PASSWORD\n\";
     expect \"sftp>\"
     send \"lcd /pken4o/shared/config/domains/edq_domain/config/fmwconfig/edq/oedq.local.home/landingarea/53\r\";
     expect \"sftp>\"
     send \"cd /HOME/IBD_EDQ/PRD\r\";
     expect \"sftp>\"
     send \"put DQ_Dashboard_*.csv\r\";
     expect \"sftp>\"
     send \"put DQD_Exceptions.csv\r\";
     expect \"sftp>\"
     send \"put DQD_Flag_Reactivation.csv\r\";
     expect \"sftp>\"
     send \"put Control_File.csv\r\";
     send \"bye\r\";
     expect \"sftp>\"
     send \"eof\r\";
"
else
     printf "\n DQ_Dashboard_$today.csv File not exists"
fi
```

Comment: I improved formatting, trying not to alter the code. Please check if I didn't break it.

Comment: Your timeout is 180 seconds. Does it sometimes take longer than that?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be. Increased timeout. Thanks!